# Thunderbird crashing

Tags: xubuntu, thunderbird

When I open web links in Thunderbird, my client freezes up or crashes. Is this a bug that I need to report or can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what the errors are when you launch thunderbird in a terminal  command is `thunderbird`.  This will help you get an answer as you question is too vague without errors to help.

Answer (score 0):

We also need your [crash report ID](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/mozilla-crash-reporter#w_viewing-crash-reports) before we can help.